# Use HTTPS for the URLs used in Flair

Tags: feature-request, flair, ssl, combined-flair

I noticed that in my [flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/1774445/anthony-geoghegan?tab=flair), the image’s `src` attribute and the link’s `href` attribute use HTTP.

It would be much better if the URLs used the HTTPS *scheme* instead of HTTP. Doing so, would avoid warning about unsafe mixed content when an HTTPS website references insecure (HTTP) resources. As security becomes more important, many sites are moving to using only HTTPS.  It’s also better to link directly to the secure/authenticated version (HTTPS) of the Stack Exchange family of sites. See [The HTTPS-Only Standard](https://https.cio.gov/everything/) for more details.

Obviously, users can change the URL scheme themselves but it would be better to have HTTPS as the default. This would be a small way for Stack Exchange to make the Internet safer and to help normalise the use of HTTPS over HTTP.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate. My search should have been more thorough. The one difference between that question and mine is that I'm advocating the use of HTTPS instead of – rather than in addition to – HTTP.